# kubernetes running pods in serial

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In my kubernetes cluster I have several kind of pods. Some pods have to wait for other pods to start. To create a cluster I have to Run all the pods in a particular serial. This requires me to continuously check for states of previous pods. I want to reduce the time taken for creating cluster.

I want to explore 2 different solutions here:

1. Is there a way I can add conditions like create pod 'a' if pod 'b' is in 'running' state?
2. Is there a way I can pull all the images when creating pod and run them later in order. Since most of the time taken to create the pod is for pulling the image.

Comment: Kubernetes has introduced the concept of services , irrespective you are increasing your pod or defining new one , make service for that pod , and than do whatever you want to do with that pod. Services are three kinds : clusterIP , nodePort , LoadBalancer.

Answer (score 1):

Pet Sets might help you with this.

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/